# cq5 AEM 'pathfield' resizing

Tags: aem, xtype

I use xtype 'multifieldpanel' from ACS.CQ library for 'multifield configuration'. And I can't set size for 'pathfield' in my dialog. I need 100% (fixed size in 'px' doesn't work too) similar with 'textfield'. I have tried all cases (width, boxMaxWidth,  autoWidth), what I do wrong??

```
<links
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Items Location"
    itemId="links"
    name="./links"
    xtype="multifield">
    <fieldConfig
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            xtype="multifieldpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <title
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    allowBlank="{Boolean}false"
                    fieldLabel="Title"
                    width="100%"
                    key="title"
                    xtype="textfield"/>
            <url
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    allowBlank="{Boolean}false"
                    fieldLabel="URL"
                    boxMaxWidth="100%"
                    key="url"
                    xtype="pathfield"/>
        </items>
    </fieldConfig>
```

Comment: try to use `autoWidth='true'`

Answer (score 2):

In the dialog,you have to give properties for pathfield as follows

name:width

type:Long

value:(as required) for ex:500

Similarly for textfield also you can follow the above procedure

1.Create a node in your component of type cq:EditConfig and name cq:editConfig, this should be a sibling of the dialog node.

2.To the cq:editConfig node add a property with name “cq:dialogMode”, type “String” and value “floating”

3.To your dialog node add two properties of type Long, name height and width and value to what the you want the size of the dialog to be.

Answer (score -1):

try `autoWidth="true" style="width: 90%"`